# Re-use "await" parameters in Scala Specs2

Tags: scala, future, specs2, matcher

Suppose I am testing results of `Futures` (see below) with `specs2`.

```
def f1():Future[String] = {...}
def f2():Future[String] = {...}
```

I have `Matchers[String]` to check the results

```
def m1():Matcher[String] = {...}
def m2():Matcher[String] = {...}
```

Now I can use `implicits` to create `Matcher[Future[String]]`.

```
def fm1():Matcher[Future[String]] = m1.await(retries=2, timeout=2.seconds)
def fm2():Matcher[Future[String]] = m2.await(retries=2, timeout=2.seconds)
```

So far so good, but I don't like that *repeating* `retries = 2` and `timeout = 2.seconds`. How can I define them just *once* and reuse them across all `await` calls in the spec ?

Comment: Probably adding an implicit class (~extension method) with implicit parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case class Retry(value:Int) extends AnyVal
case class Timeout(value:Duration) extends Anyval

implicit class MatcherWithImplicitValues[A](m:Matcher[A]) {
  def awaitWithImplicitValues(implicit r:Retry, t:Timeout) = {
    m.await(retries = r.value, timeout = t.value)
  }
}

implicit val retries = Retry(2)
implicit val timeout = Timeout(2 seconds)

m1.awaitWithImplicitValues
```

Comment: I think it would be better if the implicit parameters had a new type, like case class Retry(r: Int) and case class AwaitDuration(t: Duration). That way it cannot influence other parts that are not intended to have these implicit values.